# Parallel DataFlow Pipeline from Single Google Cloud DataFlow Job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run two separated Pipelines from one DataFlow Job similar to below question:

- [Parallel pipeline inside one Dataflow Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108773/parallel-pipeline-inside-one-dataflow-job)

If we run two separated Pipelines using Single DataFlow job using single p.run() like below:

```
    (
            p | 'Do one thing' >> beam.Create(List1)
    )
    (
            p | 'Do second thing' >> beam.Create(List2)
    )       
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

I think it will launch two separate pipelines in single Dataflow job but will it create two Bundles and will it run on two different workers?

Comment: Hi , Could you solve this problem, if it's , Can i have some question about running parallel job in dataflow please ? Thanks in advance, best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: These two sections of a graph will run under the same Dataflow job.

Dataflow paralelizes execution of work items dynamically. This means that depending on your pipeline, the amount of work that it has, etc., Dataflow may decide to schedule on the same worker or on separate workers.

Normally, if there's *enough* work on both parallel pipelines (~20s on each), then yes: They will run in parallel.