# GCP Dataflow cannot read the "pipeline.pb" file from the GCP storage location where it wrote it

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a Dataflow pipeline with the following command:

```
!python3 ~/pipelines/Beam/pipeline.py \
  --project='project_id' \
  --region='region' \
  --dataset_id='dataset_id' \
  --ingest_table_name='titanic_train' \
  --bucket='bucket_id' \
  --temp_location='gs://bucket_id/dataflow/temp' \
  --runner=DataflowRunner
```

The problem is that:

Although the pipeline successfully write the file 'pipeline.pb' to the temp_location, for example:
`gs://bucket_id/dataflow/temp/my-bq-pipeline-...../my-bq-pipeline-..../pipeline.pb`,

when it tries to read it afterwards from the same location where it wrote it, it throws the following error:

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Unable to open file: gs://bucketId/dataflow/temp/my-bq-pipeline-..../my-bq-pipeline-..../pipeline.pb.
```

I think that the same Dataflow pipeline should be able to read the file which it wrote it initially.

I tested that I am able to access that file from a notebook:

```
!gsutil cp gs://bucket_id/dataflow/temp/my-bq-pipeline-..../my-bq-pipeline-..../pipeline.pb ./pipeline.pb
```

Also, I can run the same pipeline with DirrectRunner without problems.
Any idea which might be the problem?

== update ==

After I did set-up the parameter service_account_email, as advised below by @Anish Sarangi, the new error is:

`"apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient.DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError: There is already active job named my-bq-pipeline-169... with id: 2023-10-.... If you want to submit a second job, try again by setting a different name using --job_name".`

There is not a second job with the same name because the initial name is unique and I verified in the dataflow jobs list: there is only one job with this name. This error intrigues me.

== update ==
Hi @kiran mathew, as mentioned above, there was no duplicated job_name in the printout of '`gcloud dataflow jobs list`'. There must be another, probably more subtle problem. I retested this by changing the name of the job and the problem persists. From the code, the name of the job is formatted as: '`options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = '{0}{1}'.format('my-bq-pipeline-123-',time.time_ns())`' so it is always unique. For the sake of safety, I changed also the prefix by adding '123': my-bq-pipeline-123-

Comment: Hi @crbl,from the error message it seems like a permission issue.Can you follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#security_and_permissions_for_pipelines_on_google_cloud_platform) to give required permission to the service accounts.Also check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) service account has the required permissions to access the bucket [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_gcs).Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Can you try this `python3 ~/pipelines/Beam/pipeline.py \ --project='project_id' \ --region='region' \ --dataset_id='dataset_id' \ --ingest_table_name='titanic_train' \ --bucket='bucket_id' \ --temp_location='gs://bucket_id/dataflow/temp' \ --runner=DataflowRunner --update=True`?

Comment: Hi @kiran mathew: from dataflow documentation: "Updating batch pipelines isn't supported."

Comment: Hi @crbl, you are correct. From the latest error message, it seems like you are trying to create a new dataflow pipeline with the same name to solve the error. I recommend you to change the job name in your code(‘job\_name’). You can use the `gcloud dataflow jobs list` command to find all the job names. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hi @kiran mathew, as mentioned above, there was no duplicated job_name in the printout of 'gcloud dataflow jobs list'. There must be another, probably more subtle problem. 

I retested this by changing the name of the job and the problem persists. 
From the code, the name of the job is formatted as: 'options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = '{0}{1}'.format('my-bq-pipeline-123-',time.time_ns())' so it is always unique. For the sake of safety, I changed also the prefix by adding '123': my-bq-pipeline-123-.

Comment: Hi @crbl,can you try again after changing the code as follows: ` import uuid job\_name='stackjjj'+f'{uuid.uuid4()}' `?.This code will create a unique job name.I found a similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108773/).

Comment: Hi @kiran mathew, I did and the result is unchanged, as expected:
"apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient.DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError: There is already active job named my-bq-pipeline-45chf923-0711d-4ae1-ab93-18da4011c139 with id: 2023-10-17_04_05_26-9168273849552756405. If you want to submit a second job, try again by setting a different name using --job_name."

Comment: Hi @crbl,It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to write, you should be able to read as well, could you check if the Dataflow service account has required permission on that Cloud storage bucket. By Default Dataflow uses compute engine service account, its important to pass service account explicitly while launching the pipeline, please use the following flag in your launch `--service_account_email=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: In the bucket, I do have a service account with Cloud Dataflow Service Agent role which has access to it. 
It would be strange I think for that service account, to have write rights but not to read. If Dataflow would not have permission to that bucket, it means it couldn't neither write not read to/from it.

Comment: By default it picks up default compute engine service account, I hope you are passing the Service account while launching your pipeline, in your run command, it seems like you are not passing that service account. Updating the anwer with additional context

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I did set-up the service_account_email parameter but now I get a different error: "**apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient.DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError: There is already active job named my-bq-pipeline-169... with id: 2023-10-16_...-.... If you want to submit a second job, try again by setting a different name using --job_name"**. There is not a second job with the same name because the initial name is unique and I verified in the dataflow jobs list: there is only one job with this name.